# Cannot open terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm new to ubuntu and took many days trying to solve a problem I'm having.

I searched the Internet and I have not found anything concrete that can fix it so this is my problem:

When I try to open the terminal, it is closed immediately and does not show me anything. I tried to run with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, and  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, but I get nothing and the moment it opens, it closes.

One thing I've discovered is that if I connect with the guest account then I can access the terminal.

Comment: How you are opening terminal in guest session, by `Ctrl+Alt+T` ?

Comment: no, doing click on terminal icon.

Comment: did you tried the  same in your session @Miguel,by direct clicking on it

Comment: Do you have a `set -e` line in `~/.bashrc` by any chance?

Comment: i not see this file, that file is on /home?

Answer (score 0):

seems like your profile settings are screwed up. The easiest way is to regenerate them, so go to `~/.gconf/apps` and remove de folder `gnome-terminal`

Cheers

Comment: sorry but i'm too noob with linux,  ~/ what is this directory?

Comment: it is your home folder, you can find it correspond to : `/home/yourname/`. Moreover `.gconf` is an hidden folder, you will need to press Ctrl + H to display it.

Comment: in me home folder only view this fodlers: https://gyazo.com/44905720baf28551decff8f3b5d4a132

Comment: now press Ctrl+H

Comment: I just delete the folder but still does not work

Comment: For some changes to take place, you will need to log out and back in...